# How to get the "placeholder" config of a jQuery UI sortable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

The documented way seems to be:

```
$('#sortable').sortable('option', 'placeholder');
```

But this returns an object to me, instead of the string I used at the configuration options.

I can get the value of the other config options this way. For example:

```
$('#sortable').sortable('option', 'opacity');
```

The code above returns to me the exact value I informed in the sortable configuration options.

It seems a bug to me. Anyway, if I can't get the `placeholder` value using the "normal" way, is there any other way to retrieve this information?

**EDIT**: just added a jsFiddle to demonstrate the issue - http://jsfiddle.net/hyBfm/

Comment: [It works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/gHHsN/1/). Got any sample code so we can try and see what's happening?

Comment: @ChristianVarga: Yes, see it here - http://jsfiddle.net/hyBfm/ - it seems the issue happens only from inside an event handler... take a look.

Comment: @ChristianVarga: I forked yours... http://jsfiddle.net/46Uvj/  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, it is a JQuery UI bug.

Here is the exact place:
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.sortable.js#L657

The `placeholder` option is mercyless overwritten by an internal object, in the `_createPlaceholder` funcion.

So, when you call `$('#sortable').sortable('option', 'placeholder')` **prior** to the placeholder element creation, it returns the value you informed at the configuration options (correct behaviour). But, when you make the very same call **after** dragging something (and thus the placeholder element being created), it returns the placeholder object, instead of the configuration option string (unexpected, incorrect behaviour).

I tried to fill a bug at http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8133 - but I changed the description so much because Akismet was flagging it as spam... the description became difficult to read. I hope they can acknowledge it and fix.